# How do I check how many elements are empty in an array?

Tags: c

I am trying to save how many empty elements there are in an array. This is what I have done so far but it prints out that all lines are "not empty" which is wrong.
How can I do this?

```
char arr[10][50]={NULL};
int lines;

//inserting values to arr

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   if(arr[i] == NULL){
       lines++;
       printf("empty");
   }
   else
       printf("not empty");
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: `arr` is a 2D array, why do you check `arr[i]` only instead of `arr[i][j]` (which means that you should add another loop on j) ?

Comment: Your initialisation causes a compiler warning: *"warning C4047: 'initializing': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *' "*. Didn't you notice that?

Comment: Given that `arr[i]` is a pointer to a sub-array, that pointer will never be null.  The best way of knowing how many entries in the array are valid is to keep a count as you add them.  Failing that, if you are looking for non-empty strings, you look at `arr[i][0]` and check whether it is the null byte — which is not the same as a null pointer, so you should compare with `'\0'` and not with `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: that depends on the headers.  Some systems have `#define NULL 0` or `#define NULL 0L` which does not raise that warning.

Comment: One other way to check for "emptyness" is to calculate the length of the string. If it is `0`, the string is empty: `if (strlen(arr[i]) == 0) /* empty string */;`

Comment: @WeatherVane You probably use a C++ compiler because NULL expands to 0 in C so it should raises no warning. But you're right, this is bad initialization.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting, MSVC's vcruntime.h has `#ifdef __cplusplus #define NULL 0 #else #define NULL ((void *)0) #endif`

Comment: @mikedu95 it seems to be t'other way round! (which is why I got a compiler warning).

Comment: this line: `char arr[10][50]={NULL};` results in several compiler warnings and does not produce the desired result.  Suggest: `char **arr[10] =  {NULL};`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `arr[i] == NULL` then `arr[i]` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array in `arr[i]` (i.e. `&arr[i][0]`), and that pointer will *never* be `NULL`.

I suspect you want e.g. something like `arr[i][0] == '\0'`.

Comment: Also, the initialisation of the array with `NULL` is deceiving and is probably not what the OP intended.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1. This:

   ```
   char arr[10][50]={NULL};
   ```

   should be

   ```
   char arr[10][50]={{0}}; /* Initializes the whole 2D array with zeros */
   ```

   or

   ```
   char arr[10][50]={{'\0'}}; /* Does the same thing as above; '\0' == 0 */
   ```

   The issues here were:

   1. `NULL` is usually used with pointers, but `arr` is designed to store `char`s, and `char`s aren't pointers.
   2. You should use an extra pair of braces as you are initializing a 2D array, not a 1D array.

2. Here:

   ```
   if(arr[i] == NULL)
   ```

   You check if each row of your 2D array is `NULL`. In other words, you are checking if each subarray has an address `NULL`. This will not be true and is probably contratry to what you thought.

   [@Joachim Pileborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34792514/3049655) gives more insight on this issue and a possible solution for it.

Comment: Point 1 is moot: all initializations are equal (some with automatic conversions).

Comment: @pmg Using `NULL` emits a warning for me: `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: @pmg On systems where NULL is defined as `(void *)0` you will get the warning that @Cool Guy reports.  In any event, it is semantically wrong and hindrance to understanding for the next person who has to maintain such code.